# C++: copyable view on an object

Tags: c++, reference, copy, c++17

I'm trying to make a program that deals with images, in which I have an `image` object and an `image_view` object that references a rectangle region in the image:

```
class image_view;

class image
{
    public:
        image(int width, int height);

        operator image_view() const;

    private:
        int m_width;
        int m_height;
        std::vector<pixel> m_pixels;
};

class image_view
{
    public:
        image_view(const image& ref, point origin, int width, int height);
        image_view(image_view view, point origin, int width, int height);

    private:
        const image& m_ref;
        point m_origin;
        int m_width;
        int m_height;
};
```

However, when I tried to copy an `image_view`, the compiler told me that the `operator=` member function had been deleted because of the non-static member reference. I naively tried to make my own member function with `m_ref = other.m_ref` but it didn't work since `m_ref` is `const`.

I considered using a smart pointer instead of a reference, but I didn't find a way of making a smart pointer to an already existing object.

One solution I found is the following:

```
image_view& image_view::operator= (const image_view& other)
{
    *this = image_view(other);
    return *this;
}
```

This compiles, but is it a good idea? (I might be wrong, but I feel bad about assigning stuff to `*this`.) If I do that, does that mean I have to define a destructor (even though I'm not allocating anything), move constructor and move assignment operator to satisfy the rule of 5?

Comment: Using references as members is almost always a bad idea. Use a pointer.

Comment: Try running that `operator=` your created. You *will* get a stack overflow.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/957087/1896169 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/892133/1896169

Comment: Set image as a smart pointer, then have inside image_view a smart pointer member to it.

Comment: I tried to run it, and it worked as expected (I'm using gcc 7.3.0 with `-std=c++17`). Neil Butterworth: do you mean a raw pointer? Isn't that bad?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Can you explain why references as members are bad? And why pointers as members better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to express a non-owning, non-null wrapper that rebinds on assignment, the easiest way to do that is to use [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper):

```
class image_view
{
public:
    image_view(const image& ref, point origin, int width, int height);
    image_view(image_view view, point origin, int width, int height);

private:
    std::reference_wrapper<image const> m_ref;
    point m_origin;
    int m_width;
    int m_height;
};
```

The default copy constructor and assignment operator will do the right thing.