# Why is it illegal/immoral to reseat a reference?

Tags: c++, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are references not reseatable in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728233/why-are-references-not-reseatable-in-c)

I am trying to more or less swap two reference variables (as practice, I could have swapped the actual variables). I tried doing this by making a temporary variable and making one of the references equal the other, but this got shot down by the compiler. Here is an example:

```
void Foo()
{
   //code
   int& ref1 = a;
   int& ref2 = b;
   int temp;

   temp = ref1;
   ref1 = ref2;
   ref2 = temp;

   //or, better yet
   std::swap(ref1, ref2);
}
```

I got an error, and looked on the faq lite. It details that they cannot be reseated, but does not explain why. Why?

[Here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#reseating-refs) is a link to the Faq Lite for reference (<---, get it?).

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728233/why-are-references-not-reseatable-in-c

Comment: Beside the point, but your logic should be: temp = ref1; ref1 = ref2; ref2 = temp;  The way you have it now, temp = ref1 = ref2 = a.

Comment: And Stroustrup's rationale: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728233/why-are-references-not-reseatable-in-c/728272#728272

Comment: Oops, that was a mistake. Thanks Bill.

Comment: Your code compiles fine - it swaps the values of a and b. ref1 refers to a and ref2 refers to b (this isn't swapped). I think the underlying question has been answered, but could you clarify what "error" you're getting, because I can't see one.

Comment: It did not compile on mine. I think my compiler knew what I was trying to do.

Comment: Please close this, I get my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because there is no syntax to do it:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 1;
int & r = x;
```

Now if I say:

```
r = y;
```

I assign the value of y to x. If I wanted to reseat I would need some special syntax:

```
r @= y;    // maybe?
```

As the main reason for using references is as parameters and return types of functions, where this is not an issue, it didn't seem to C++'s designers that this was a path worth going down.

Comment: Oh, I never considered what exactly the assignment operator was doing in this instance. So r = y would just set x to 1?

Answer (score 7):

A reference is an alias to object.
Alias can not be changed (we are not spies ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Because references don't have an address of their own (if they do that is implementation dependent, and you can't access them with the & operator directly).

The & operator is used to get the address of the thing that the reference is referring to.

Whereas a pointer does have an address of its own and you can access it with the & operator.

```
int x = 4;
int *p = &x;
//p holds the address of x
//&p holds the address of p.

int &r = x;
//&r holds the address of x
```

And if something doesn't have an address of its own then it can't store a value inside of it. And if it can't store a value inside of it, then it can't be changed.

I think the [parashift C++ FAQ on references](http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/references.html#faq-8.1) says it best:

> Important note: Even though a
>   reference is often implemented using
>   an address in the underlying assembly
>   language, please do not think of a
>   reference as a funny looking pointer
>   to an object. A reference is the
>   object. It is not a pointer to the
>   object, nor a copy of the object. It
>   is the object.

and again in [FAQ 8.5](http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/references.html#faq-8.5) :

> Unlike a pointer, once a reference is
>   bound to an object, it can not be
>   "reseated" to another object. The
>   reference itself isn't an object (it
>   has no identity; taking the address of
>   a reference gives you the address of
>   the referent; remember: the reference
>   is its referent).

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code again:

```
temp = ref1;
ref2 = temp;
ref1 = ref2;
```

References are aliases. All operations that you do on the reference are performed on the object it references. In your code above, how should the compiler magically know that you aren't trying to assign the values to referenced variables, but are rather trying to change the reference itself? There's no syntax to indicate the difference between that, and, for example:

```
ref1 = 3;
```

which you'd normally expect to assign a value 3 to the object referenced by `ref1`.

In short, this is simply by design. If you want "reseatable" references, then you just use pointers (or, if you want to avoid accidential pointer arithmetic, `boost::optional`).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike pointers, references are designed to guarantee that they always refer to an object. To meet this gaurantee, the compiler requires that all references be initialized in their declaration and disallows you from reassigning them.

Similar to pointers, reference variables allow you to access the same instance of an object through multiple locations - but unlike pointers, reference provide a greater level of safety.