# Changing References in C++

Tags: c++, reference

From C++ FAQ

"How can you reseat a reference to make it refer to a different object?"

But when I do this it compiles and executes fine.

```
    int f = 5;
int y =4;
int& u = f;
u = y;
B& bRef = B();
bRef = B();
```

This code is inside my main() function.

Link of C++ FAQ https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#reseating-refs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't reseat the reference, you simply assign to the referred object.

```
#include <iostream>

struct X{
  void operator=(X const&){
    std::cout << "Woops, assignment!\n";
  }
};

int main(){
 X x, y;
 X& rx = x;
 rx = y;
}
```

[Guess what this prints.](http://ideone.com/fuLdm)

Answer (score 1):

By saying int &u=f; and then u=y; you are assigning the value of y to f as f is referred to by the reference u. Hence you are not reseating the reference but simply changing the value of f.

[Why is it illegal/immoral to reseat a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207906/why-is-it-illegal-immoral-to-reseat-a-reference)

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the reference while saying `u = y;`. You are just assigning value of `y` to variable `f` which still referred by `u`.

Please check the value of `f` to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

when you call 'u = y;',you just assign value of y to the variable that u reference to(its f).
Basically,reference is implemented as a 'pointer' under varies compiler, the operation 'u = y;', just set the memory to value of y.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a reference cannot be changed after it has been initialized; it always refers to the same object it was initialized to denote..