# Problems returning a const reference (no a reference to a const)

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I want to return a const reference so I cannot change the object itself but I can call their non-const methods. But I don't know how to do it.

With pointers is easy, I can choose between a const pointer (const myclass*) or a pointer to const values (myclass const*). But with references it seems not working the same way, all I've got it is a reference to a const object so I cannot call non-const methods.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

```
class A {
   int a;
public:
   auto get() const { return a; }
   auto set(int i) -> void { a = i; }
};

class B {
  A a_;
public:
  auto get() const -> const A& { return a_; }
};
```

I can do:

```
B b;
cout << b.get().get();
```

But not:

```
B b;
b.get().set(100); // compiler error
```

I don't want

```
class B {
  A a_;
public:
  auto get() -> A& { return a_; }
};

B b;
A a;
b.get() = a; // I don't want this!
```

Comment: "*I want to return a const reference so I cannot change the object itself but I can call their non-const methods*". These are contradictory requirements.

Comment: See [What is the xy problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think you need this? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You can't change which object a reference refers to, so a "const reference to non-const" (`T& const`) in the manner of `T* const` would be meaningless.

Comment: @molbdnilo you can have a `const T&` that references a (non-const) `T`, but I think thats the wrong direction for this question

Comment: If you want to be able to modify the object through its members, but not assign to it, you can't do that with pointers either (unless you make it entirely non-assignable).

Comment: *"I want to return a const reference so I cannot change the object itself"* - You say this but then your example tries to change the object by calling `set(100)`...?

Comment: `b.get() = a` *doesn't change the object itself* by the way. It just calls `b.get().operator=(a);` which overwrites all the members of b with the ones from a, but b is still b and not a.

Comment: _"I can choose between a const pointer (const myclass*) or a pointer to const values (myclass const*)."_ -- The two declarations are the same thing. A "const pointer" would be `myclass * const` so that `const` applies to `*` rather than to `myclass`. See [What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)

Comment: Hmm... are you trying to ask about [Changing References in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695657/changing-references-in-c)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have "partial mutability" in that way, not without removing assignment completely from `A`.
(Despite your claim that this is easy with pointers, that situation is exactly the same - you need to either disallow `b.get()->set(100)` or allow `*b.get() = a`.)

One thing you can do is add a level of indirection by way of a proxy object:

```
class A_Setter
{
public:
    A_Setter(A* a): the_a(a) {}
    A_Setter& operator=(const A_Setter&) = delete;

    void set(int x) { the_a->set(x); }
private:
    A* the_a;
};

class B {
    A a_;
public:
    A_setter get() { return A_setter(&a_); }
};
```

Now `b.get().set(100);` will compile, not `b.get() = a;`.

Answer (score 1):

> Problems returning a const reference (no a reference to a const)

There is technically no such thing as const reference. References do not have top level cv-qualifiers. Const reference *colloquially* means a reference to const.

> I want to return a ... reference so I cannot change the object itself

Objects cannot be modified through references to const, so that would work.

> ... but I [want to] call their non-const methods.

Non-const member functions can be called only through references to non-const. There is no category of reference that can satisfy both of your wants. They are contradictory.

> With pointers is easy, I can choose between a const pointer (`const myclass*`) or a pointer to const values (`myclass const*`).

Those do not achieve what you want either. You can modify the pointed object through a const pointer (to non-const), and you cannot call const member functions of the pointed object through a (non-const) pointer to const. Neither achieves your both wants.

---

P.S. Returning a const (or volatile) qualified pointer - or any other built-in type - is meaningless because function calls to such function are prvalue expressions and prvalues of non-class types do not have cv-qualifiers, so the qualifiers of such return type would always be ignored. This is not to be confused with returning pointer to cv-qualified types which is meaningful.