# Reseating a reference in C++. How the code does compiles?

Tags: c++

As pointed out in various questions on stackoverflow:
[References are not reseatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728233/why-are-references-not-reseatable-in-c)

[Immoral to reseat a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207906/why-is-it-illegal-immoral-to-reseat-a-reference)

I am able to compile out the below code snippet :

```
int a1 =10;
int b = 15;

int& intref = a1;

intref = b;
```

reading discussion over the above cited reference, I am in a view that the above code should not compile at all. But it does. Can someone please point me out to a more explanatory resource regarding C++ references? Or give me a reason what wrong am I doing.

I am using MinGW 4.9.1 Win32 compiler, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, references are *not* reseatable. What's happening is that the reference (which refers to `a1`) is being assigned the value in `b`. After the assignment, both `intref` and `a1` will be equal to `b`.

Comment: where I can find a code snippet, which actually gives me the error regarding "reseating" of references?

Comment: @trivalent there's no error, because the language doesn't give you a syntax that would even let you try. The `=` sign here has two different meanings, the first one creates the reference and the second one does a value assignment.