# Modifying reference variables, not the variable they alias

Tags: c++, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Reference, change the refered variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713266/c-reference-change-the-refered-variable)

I know that references in c++ are just pointers that get dereferenced for you when you use them. This question is about how to access the underlying pointer and change it.

Consider this code:

```
int x;
int& x_ref = x;              //now equivalent to x
int* x_ptr = &x;         //stores address of x
int* x_ref_ptr = &x_ref; //ALSO stores address of x

int&* x_ref_ptr_ref = ???; //what would this mean?
```

I'm trying to change where a reference points after initialization. I have no concern for type safety or proper practices. Does the c++ language have any tool to let me accomplish this?

Comment: What you "know" may not actually be true. Pointers are pointers, and references are references. They're different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible *by design*. By using a reference instead of a pointer, you decide to never change its target after declaration, with all entailing drawbacks and advantages (one of which is its "automatic dereferencing". Read the [Wikipedia entry on references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29) carefully.

You will need to switch to pointers.

Comment: That article says that typical compilers implement this internally as a pointer. Still 'by design' answers my question.

Answer (score 5):

There is no pointer to reference, it's ill-formed. A reference is an alias to an object. How would a pointer to an alias work?

Also, it's a *feature* of the language that a reference can't be reseated. A reseatable reference is a pointer.