# Passing an Array Reference in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, reference

I'm new to C++ and running into a lot of sytax all the time.. I havn't been able to find a concrete answer to this in a while now. I'm trying to run this piece of code:

```
void test(char &testChar){
    char B[3] = {"BB"};
    testChar = B;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char A[3] = {"AB"};
    test(A);
    std::cout << A;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to pass my Variable `A` to function `test` and have that function replace the content of `A` with the content of local variable `B`, and then print that out. How should this be done?

Comment: An array is not a `char&`, and you cannot assign arrays to one another. Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: he's not asking to assign an array to another - he's asking to replace the *content* of an array with that of another

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: In what sense does that action differ from _assignment_?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: you *cannot* assign an array to another (using an assignment operator) - you *can* copy the contents of an array to another (using a loop eg.).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: Yet, beyond the fact that C++ allows one and not the other (for legacy reasons), semantically the two operations are utterly indistinct. What do you think happens when you do `int x = 5, y = 4; y = x;`? You assign `x` to `y`, which _replaces the contents of the `int` with that of another_. What Christian _cannot_ do is use _assignment notation_ -- he is _absolutely_ attempting to do that at the present time, as you can clearly see from his code, and it is _this_ that I refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reference to array should be this

```
void test(char (&testChar)[3]){
 // code
}
```

But in your test function `testChar = B;` expression is wrong. you need to [explicitly string copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) (second reference doesn't change in C++, not like pointer) for this you may like to read: [C++ Reference, change the refered variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713266/c-reference-change-the-refered-variable)

**Edit**: As @ChristianSjöstedt commented.

Python is  "dynamic typed language" where type and value of variable can be change, Where as in C++ one you declare the type of a variable it doesn't change.

```
 i = 10         # reference to int 
 i = "name"     # reference to str
```

this is possible in Python but not in C++ (and C)

C/C++ are static language mean "statically typed language" . for example type of a variable can't be change and defined statically at compilation time.

```
int i = 10;
```

`i` in int can be char.

[Dynamic type languages versus static type languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125367/dynamic-type-languages-versus-static-type-languages)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses!
I'm coming form a python background where everything just works so its a lot of re-schooling going on for me right now.

doing this: (char (&testChar)[3]) and assigning elements individually solved my problem.

thanks again

Comment: @ChristianSjöstedt welcom! :)  you should consider juanchopanza's answer. he posted good technique.

Comment: @ChristianSjöstedt wait Python is dynamic language where as c++ and c are not, wait I updated something.

Comment: @ChristianSjöstedt By the change I am not good in both but I hope upto some extend this will help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> "Passing an Array Reference in C++"

Assuming you want to pass a reference to an array to a function, and set the elements of that array to those stored in another one, you can use `std::copy`, since arrays are not assignable. It is better to use a template function to have a handle on the size of the array:

```
template <size_t N>
test( char (&testChar)[N] )
{
  char B[N] = {"BB"};
  stc::copy(B, B+N, testChar);
}
```

But I suggest you use `std::array`, which is copyable and assignable:

```
template <size_t N>
test(std::array<char,N>& testarray; )
{
  std::array<char, N> B = {"BB"};
  teasArray = B;
}
```

Comment: And you still won't be able to assign one to the other.

Comment: @ChristianSjöstedt: Your C++ book covers this, too. It would save us from answering this _again_ (it has already been done many times) if you'd read it!

Answer (score 0):

Use either `std::array` for fixed size arrays or `std::vector` for dynamic (variable length) ones.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you are probably looking for

```
#include <string.h>

void test(char *testChar){
    char B[3] = {"BB"};
    strcpy(testChar, B);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char A[3] = {"AB"};
    test(A);
    std::cout << A;

    return 0;
}
```

but there are all sorts of reasons why code like this is a bad idea. If you want to do string manipulation then you should start with the `std::string` class instead of getting into the horrible mess that is arrays and pointers in C++.