# c++ references appear reassigned when documentation suggests otherwise

Tags: c++, reference

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713266/c-reference-change-the-refered-variable) question you can't change what a reference refers to. Likewise the C++ Primer 5th Edition states

> Once we have defined a reference, there is no way to make that reference
>   refer to a different object. When we use a reference, we always get the object to
>   which the reference was initially bound.

However the following code [compiles](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php) and prints the value 4 which looks to me like the reference was changed?? Please elaborate if this is or is not so.

```
int a = 2;
int b = 4;
int &ref = a;
ref = b;
cout << ref;
```

Comment: So what happens if you print out `a` as well?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are not reassigning a reference. A reference acts as an alias for a variable. In this case, `ref` is an alias for `a`, so

```
ref = b;
```

is the equivalent of

```
a = b;
```

You can easily check that by printing out the value of `a`:

```
std::cout << a << std::endl; // prints 4
```

Comment: If I am not `reassigning the reference` what is that called? I am using the assignment operator and in the context of a reference. Also, it may help if you post an illegal use of an attempted reassignment of a reference.

Comment: @wal: It's just assignment.  Your code is behaviourally very similar to `int *ref = &a; *ref = b; cout << *ref`.

Comment: @wal I have explained what is going on. "You are doing the equivalent of `a = b;`". There is nothing illegal about that. You are just assigning a value to the variable that the reference refers to.

Comment: thanks, that last comment cleared it up. it is subtly but importantly different from the 'equiavlent' c# so am glad I asked.

Comment: @wal This can be quite a confusing issue, but once you think of a reference exactly as an alias, it all starts to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can understand how references work by comparing their behavior to that of a pointer.  A pointer can be thought of as the name of the *address* of a variable; however a reference is just the name of the variable itself--it is an *alias*.  An alias, once set, can never be changed whereas you can assign a pointer a new address if you want.  So you have:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 4;
    int* ptr_a = &a;
    int& ref_a = a;

    ptr_a = &b;  //Ok, assign ptr_a a new address
    ref_a = &b;  //Error--invalid conversion.  References are not addresses.
    &ref_a = &b; //Error--the result of the `&` operator is not an R-value, i.e. you can't assign to it.

    return 0;
}
```