# Proper way to pass a pointer? c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a simple question that I am not 100% sure on.

Let us say I have a Entity class, that handles objects on the screen. Let us say the Entity class has two float variables, 'x' and 'y' (aka coordinates). Also let us say the entity I am passing has already been declared and is in memory.

I have another class that handles camera movement. It requires an entity to center on. The entity that it is centered on can changed, so I need to use a pointer here I believe. The only thing I do here is grab the X and Y variables when needed. Nothing is changed here.

I've defined it as

```
void StarField::ChangeFollowEntity(Entity* newFollowEntity) {
    followEntity = newFollowEntity;
}
```

where followEntity is also an Entity class. I would call ChangeFollowEntity(..) to change the entity. Is this actually correct?

I've also seen however this:

```
void StarField::ChangeFollowEntity(Entity newFollowEntity) {
    followEntity = &newFollowEntity;
}
```

In both cases followEntity is defined as Entity* followEntity; .. What does the second example exactly do here? From what I understand, & would typically be used as a reference type. Maybe it is incorrect to do to begin with.

I am pretty sure I shouldn't be using a reference in this case because the followEntity changes, which references I believe cannot change and must be defined.

So my question is, is my first example correct and the right way to do it? What does the second example do exactly?

Comment: The second version is very very incorrect...

Comment: In the order asked, Yes, and dangles a pointer likely-later to be dereferenced and invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Does someone want to address his comment about whether a reference would work?

Comment: (const) reference should also work. `void StarField::ChangeFollowEntity(const Entity& newFollowEntity)`

Comment: If you use & in a declaration you get a reference, but In the `followEntity = &newFollowEntity;` case & takes the address of newFollowEntity giving full-on pointer behaviour. followEntity is assigned the address of newFollowEntity. This usage is (partially) correct within the bounds of the function, but ends in disaster as already documented in the answers as soon as the function returns.

Comment: For safety, I'd recommend wrapping `Entity*` a bit differently and use a [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Used correctly, shared_ptr prevents the entity from being destroyed while the camera is using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second version ::

```
void StarField::ChangeFollowEntity(Entity newFollowEntity) {
    followEntity = &newFollowEntity;
}
```

You pass the `newFollowEntity` by value, so when your function is called from `main` or from where ever! A copy of the object is made (using the copy constructor) and sent to the function `ChangeFollowEntity`, and after the completion of the execution of the function, your `followEntity` has the address of the **COPY** of the object, which gets destroyed after the completion of the function call, so your pointer `followEntity` is left dangling, which is undefined behavior if you access any entity using the `followEntity`

First is the correct way to do it!!

Answer (score 1):

> What does the second example exactly do here?

Your second example creates a `Entity newFollowEntity` **which only exists for the duration of that function call.**

The address of that variable is stored, and then the variable is destroyed, leaving a [dangling pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/).

That's bad.

> I am pretty sure I shouldn't be using a reference in this case because the followEntity changes, which references I believe cannot change

You **can** use a reference in this case.  A referenced object can be changed - you are probably recalling that [a reference cannot be reassigned.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713266)

Answer (score 1):

The second example does the following:

1. When the function is called a new `Entity` object `newFollowEntiry`
   is created and whatever is passed into the function is used to
   construct it
2. Then an address of that local stack based object is taken and
   assigned to `followEntiry` to be stored presumably.
3. When the function execution is complete `newFollowEntiry` is destroyed
4. The `folowEntity` pointer is now pointing at a location in stack where
   there is not `Entity` object anymore.
5. BUG