# What does "reference can never be made to refer to another object" mean?

Tags: c++, reference

I read about C++ reference variables and somewhere I found this:

> A declaration of a const reference is redundant since reference can never be made to refer to another object.

what does it mean?

Here, for example, I can change the object that the reference is referring to:

```
void p(int& i) {
    int a = 7,c = 0;
    i = a;
}
```

So what does it mean that "Reference can never be made to refer to another object"?

thanks in advance.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728233/why-are-references-not-reseatable-in-c

Comment: The best way to look at references is as a different name for what they're referencing: `int i; int& r = i;` Here, `r` is a different name for `i`. It is crucial to understand that `r` does *not* point to `i`. `r` *is* `i`. And it cannot be anything else than `i`. That's why the text says "can never be made to refer to another object."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means, given this code

```
int a;
int b;
int& ref = a;
```

that, once you've initialized `ref` to refer to `a`, there is no way you can make it refer to `b` or any other variable.

Any change you make to the reference will reflect on the variable that you used to initialize it with. The reference (which itself is not even a proper object) stays intact.

Also, a reference is only usable as long as the object it refers to stays alive.

Comment: Is this true for C++ language standards C++ 17, C++ 20? I am doing something quite similar, and I find that I can reassign the reference variable to another object. I am quite puzzled by [this](https://onlinegdb.com/D1mkVOyZ6). I am using Windows 10 and MSVC compiler. For the life of me, I can't figure out where I am going wrong!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to envision it is to speak in terms of pointers:

```
// reference                     // equivalent pointer code
int& r = a;                      int* const r = &a;

r = b;                           *r = b;

function(r);                     function(*r);
```

That is, at the moment of declaration, a reference declares an alias to an existing object's memory location. Then, any use of the reference is equivalent to dereferencing a pointer to that memory location.

Now, what of a *const* reference ? Well it would be:

```
// reference                     // equivalent pointer code
int& const r = a;                int* const const r = &a;

int const& const r = a;          int const* const const r = &a;
```

which makes the redundancy quite obvious, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are not changing what `i` is pointing at. It is changing the VALUE of `i` to the value of `a`. If you where to display the address of `i`, you'd see it is different from `a`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `int &r = x;` this means that `r` refers to `x` and every time you change `r`, you really change `x`. Likewise every time you change `x` that change is visible through `r`.

Now what "Reference can never be made to refer to another object" means is that once you do `int &r =x`, you can't make `r` refer to `y`. You can do `r = y;`, but all that does is to set `x` equal to `y`. It does not means that changing `r` afterwards will change `y` nor does it mean that changes to `y` will be visible through `r`.