# Why a reference parameter can be re-seted?

Tags: c++, reference

Why I can't re-set the value of a reference but I can do that if the reference is a function parameter? For example the following code will work without a problem:

```
void foo(int& i)
{
}

int main()
{
    int i; foo(i);
    int j; foo(j);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can do the same in both cases. But you're not changing the reference, you're changing the object it refers to. Your code doesn't exhibit the issue you're asking about.

Comment: What is the thing that surprises you?  The program you are showing successfully does nothing as one would expect.  Also please check your wording.  Do you mean *“can”* or *“can not”*?  And what does “re-set the value of a reference” mean?

Comment: @EJP based on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728233/why-are-references-not-reseatable-in-c, you can't re-set the reference value, but when it is a function parameter, you can call the function multiple times with different value for the reference parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'reference parameter re-set' here. The function reference formal parameter doesn't even exist until you call the function, with a new actual argument value and possibly a new location on the stack every time you call it. Every time you call the function you are initializing a *new* reference (to be passed as the actual argument value), just as you would be with `int &k = i;` in the `main()` of your example.