# Why do I get this error (C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'B') when assigning to a reference?

Tags: c++, boost

In this template function, I am trying to retrieve at element from a boost ptr_map. I have omitted error handling code for clarity.

```
template <typename K, class T>
class A
{
public:
    void TryGet(const K &key, T &o) { o = mObjects.at(key); }
private:
    boost::ptr_map<K, T> mObjects;
};

typedef A<std::string, B> myClass;
```

I get the compiler error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'B'. Why does the assignment of the return value of mObjects.at() to a reference need access to an assignment operator of the instantiated class? What is the correct way to return this value?

Comment: your `TryGet` is declared to return a `bool` but there is no `return`

Comment: Why does assignment require assignment? Um...

Comment: It probably has something to do with `B`, which you haven't shown.

Comment: @tobi303 I omitted the return for clarity.

Comment: @nobar B has no operator=, which is the source of the error. My question is based around the semantics of assignment to a reference,

Comment: sorry, but I dont think incorrect code adds clarity

Comment: Rather than leaving us to guess about the implementation of `B`, I think you should include a very simple version of it that demonstrates the problem.  Telling us that it "has no operator=" is ambiguous -- do you mean that it was explicitly removed with `=delete`?.  If so, that needs to be clear in the question (by showing the code), and furthermore in that case, your problem really has nothing to do with "assignment to a reference".

Comment: @DrewS `x = y` means `x.operator=(y)`, for class types

Comment: @tobi303 fixed the code to remove the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the assignment of the return value of mObjects.at() to a reference need access to an assignment operator of the instantiated class?

When you are assigning to a reference, you are assigning to the object that the reference references.

```
int i = 0;
int& iRef = i;   // There is no assignment, just initializing the reference.
iRef = 10;       // Same as i = 10
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

What you are seeing is the equivalent of:

```
int j = 10;
int& jRef = j;
iRef = jRef;     // Same as i = j
```

Comment: I dont see how this is equivalent. The mObjects.at(...) returns a reference to an object. So I would have thought the line o = mObjects.at(...) is closer to your int &ref = i (i.e. no assignment)

Answer (score 2):

I think that you're asking "why can't I re-target a reference"?

What I mean by that is that you create a reference (let's call it `ref1`) that references a variable `a`  (`int& ref1 = a;`) and then if you have another reference (`ref2`) that references a variable `b` (int& ref2 = b;`), you want to know why:

```
ref1 = ref2;
```

doesn't change `ref1` to reference `b`, instead of doing `a = b`.

Is that correct?
If so, the answer is that "that's not now references work in C++". They can only be initialized once, and after that they cannot be changed.

Here's a discussion of this topic: [Why are references not reseatable in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728233/why-are-references-not-reseatable-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Now I get it.  You don't know how references work in C++.  Maybe your familiarity with Java is throwing you off track.  In C++, references are simple *aliases* -- so you are attempting to assign directly to the object in question (which you have indicated is not legal).  In Java, ["references"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523) are roughly the equivalent of C++ [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).  By wrapping your unnasignable types in those, you might be able to make this approach work.

```
boost::ptr_map<K, shared_ptr<T> > mObjects;

void TryGet(const K &key, shared_ptr<T> & o )
   {
   o = mObjects.at(key);
   }
```

Comment: note: OP code wouldn't work in java either, since the object reference was passed by value (i.e. `o = bla` won't change the argument in the caller)

Comment: @M.M: Good point.  That's one of the nice things about C++ -- it's easy to remember how parameters are passed because pass-by-reference and pass-by-pointer have an explicit syntax.  Java, and others, have subtle rules about how parameters are passed (and assigned).  I was just making a guess that the OP was thinking in terms of Java, based on the different way that Java uses the term "reference".

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your code is

```
boost::ptr_map<K, T> mObjects;
```

boost::ptr_map need tow classes with overloaded assignment operator. You must overload assignment operator in Type B, if you want to use boost::ptr_map