# Why is "re-seating" a reference not a compiler error?

Tags: c++

Re-seating a reference in C++ is [explicitly disallowed as a design decision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728233/why-are-references-not-reseatable-in-c). But why is it not a hard compiler error? Would it complicate the language to make this an error?

Comment: The language syntax doesn't have any possibility for reseating a reference

Comment: Compiler designers did better than making it a hard compiler error: they made it syntactically impossible.

Comment: It may be syntactically meaningless to try to reseat a reference, but sometimes it's useful to take advantage of the "const" property of a reference; but this hides logic bugs since it is not a hard error.

Comment: @user7835540 You have `const` pointers and smart-pointers for that, though.

Comment: @Dai In the case where type deduction is involved, pointer dereferencing can make the code harder to read.

Comment: What is not a compiler error?

Comment: @user7835540 maybe you should post an example of the code you are talking about in your comment "it's useful to take advantage of the "const" property of a reference; but this hides logic bugs since it is not a hard error". Reference reseating is syntactically impossible, therefore whatever you have in mind that "is not a hard error" is not reference reseating.

Comment: It would not complicate the language but miss the point of a reference. If you have `int a; int b; int& c = a; c = b;` the last assignment is not an error at all. It is actually the point of a reference to be able to change the value "pointed". Il you want mutable references, look at std::reference_wrapper.