# C++ object address changes when trying to add to map. New to C++

Tags: c++, c++17

I am fairly new to C++ and have been stuck for a few days and think I am making a very silly mistake.
`

```
void Room::AddExit(const std::string key, const Item& item){
    std::cout << "Location before: " << &item << std::endl;
    this->exits[key] =  item;
    std::cout << "Location after: " << &this->exits[key] << std::endl;
}
```

This will print the address to the item before which is correct however when accessing from map then gives different address.

It's strange because I'm trying to use methods on item it will work in line, however, will not after as if it has gone out of scope. However, I still believe that the address should be the same before and after regardless.

Comment: The assignment `this->exits[key] =  item` *copies* the `item` object. The object in the map is a separate object, distinct from `item`.

Comment: All STL containers own their objects.

Comment: Is it not passed in by reference? Sorry I am very new to C++.

Comment: I suppose the real question is why you are interesting in the item's address and not the value of the item. And if you are interested in the item's address for some reason then why don't you add the item's address to the map instead of just adding the item.

Comment: @Bizz It's passed by reference, and copied from that reference. You cannot add a reference to a map.

Comment: @Bizz How is `exits' declared?

Comment: @Bizz In C++ objects are values, in many other languages (Java, C#) objects are references. If you are coming to C++ from such a language it takes some getting used to that when you write `a = b;` what is happening is that an object is being copied not a reference.

Comment: [Why does assignment to a reference use the copy assignment operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55766515/why-does-assignment-to-a-reference-use-the-copy-assignment-operator)

Comment: @John std::map<std::string, Room> exits I need this as reference as it may be changed so needs to change globally not just in the scope. Thanks

Comment: @Bizz Like I said you cannot store a reference in a map. If you want to store an object's address in a map you use a pointer `std::map<std::string, Room*>` and `this->exits[key] =  &item;`. Of course you then will have the issue of making sure that your pointers in the map refer to objects that actually exist. That's up to you, C++ won't make it happen for you.

Comment: The alternative to a pointer is a `std::reference_wrapper<Room>`, which behaves in many ways like a reference

Comment: If you want the same semantics as java then use `std::shared_ptr`, you can safely pass in into and out of functions and put it in containers without lifetime issues and the objects don't change their address, it is slower than passing value objects around though, and you need to implement a `Clone` method for copying as you would do in java