# C++ reference to local variable that went out of scope

Tags: c++

Very simple question, which most likely calls for an explanation on how references work and why my understanding is flawed.

Given the simple code snippet below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Foo
{
    std::string &ref;
    Foo(std::string &bar) : ref(bar) { }
};

int main()
{
    std::string s1 = "foo1";
    Foo f(s1);
    f.ref[0] = 'b';
    std::cout << s1 << std::endl; // prints boo1
    {
        std::string f2("tmp");
        f.ref = f2;
    } 
    // shouldn't f.ref be dangling by now?
    std::cout << f.ref; // prints tmp
}

Output:
```

My understanding is that f2 will be destroyed at the end of that block, thus f.ref will be a dangling reference. 
What is really going on?

Comment: Do you think f is still valid?  Does std::string have an assignment operator? What does s1 hold at the end?

Comment: See [Why are references not reseatable in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728233/why-are-references-not-reseatable-in-c)

Comment: Yeah just realized that and pulled the comment out.  I was off thinking like it was a pointer.

Comment: Not fully a dupe because of your references, but relevant to your thinking: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) (Even if you had a dangling reference, your program would not be guaranteed to malfunction.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f.ref = f2` is the same as `s1 = s2`, because `f.ref` and `s1` are both names for the same `string` object.

Perhaps you are mixing up the concepts of initialization of a reference,  and assignment of objects. A reference can only be initialized once (and in fact, *must* be initialized on creation).

In the initialization `ref(bar)`, `ref` is initialized to refer to the same object `bar` refers to (which is also the same object as is called `s1`).

In the assignment expression `f.ref = f2;` the assignment operator is called for the object which `f.ref` names.