# Why can't we reassign the reference

Tags: c++, reference

I've read everywhere that the references cannot be reassigned. but I am not getting the reason.
Consider the below code

```
int x=11; // variable initialization  
int z=67;  
int &y=x; // y reference to x  
int &y=z; // y reference to z, but throws a compile-time error.
```

Here, y References to x as an alias, so when we say &y=z now it should alias to z instead of y. why can't we reassign it?

Comment: C/C++ is not a thing. There is C++ and there is C. And C doesn't have references as types.

Comment: You can use scopes: `{int &y = x; /* do something with y */} int &y = z;`

Comment: A reference is an alias or a pseudonym. This is a different concept than a pointer. You can make a pointer point to different entities. But pseudonyms stay the same. Like if you give one of your friends a nickname. Normally you won't assign this nickname to another friend of yours. You could... but you won't! :-) In the same way a reference is intentionally not reassignable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are references not reseatable in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728233/why-are-references-not-reseatable-in-c)

Comment: @BenjaminBihler Got your point.Thank you

Comment: Thanks @Jorengarenar. It solves my doubts