# Polymorphic reference type

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism

I have this simple piece of code (Command pattern) that doesn't work as expected.

Usually a polymorphic type would work when it's manipulated by either a pointer or a reference. So if `Command` is an interface and `m_command` is a reference, then `SetCommand` should work for different concrete types of `Command` (eg, `CommandLightOn` and `CommandGarageDoorOpen`) ? It turns out not the case. Once `SimpleRemote` is instantiated with `CommandLightOn`, the `SetCommand` has completely no effect. In this example, attempt to change the underlying object to `CommandGarageDoorOpen` has no errors, but no effect either.

It works fine if `m_command` in `SimpleRemote` is changed to pointer type.
So the question is why reference type fails to work in this case?

```
class SimpleRemote
{
public:
    SimpleRemote( Command& command ) : m_command{ command } {}

    void SetCommand( Command& command )
    {
        m_command = command;  //<-- broken
    }

    void ButtonPressed()
    {
        m_command.execute();
    }

private:
    Command& m_command;
};
```

Output:

> Light is on
>
> Light is on  #<-- expect that it prints "Garage door is up"

Full code of this example (simple Command pattern):

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class Light
{
public:
    void On()
    {
        cout << "Light is on\n";
    }

private:
};

class GarageDoor
{
public:
    void Up()
    {
        cout << "Garage door is up\n";
    }

private:
};


// the Command interface
class Command
{
public:
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};


class CommandLightOn : public Command
{
public:
    CommandLightOn( Light light ) : m_light{ light }{}

    void execute() override
    {
        m_light.On();
    }   

private:
    Light m_light;
};


class CommandGarageDoorOpen : public Command
{
public:
    CommandGarageDoorOpen( GarageDoor door ) : m_door{door} {}  

    void execute() override
    {
        m_door.Up();
    }

private:
    GarageDoor m_door;
};


class SimpleRemote
{
public:
    SimpleRemote( Command& command ) : m_command{ command } {}

    void SetCommand( Command& command )
    {
        m_command = command;
    }

    void ButtonPressed()
    {
        m_command.execute();
    }

private:
    Command& m_command;
};


int main()
{
    Light light;
    CommandLightOn light_on( light );

    SimpleRemote remote( light_on );
    remote.ButtonPressed();

    GarageDoor door;
    CommandGarageDoorOpen door_open( door );
    remote.SetCommand( door_open );
    remote.ButtonPressed();
}
```

Comment: Reference can be initialized only once, after that you cannot change referenced object. Here `m_command = command;  //<-- broken` you invoke assignment operator of `Command` class.

Comment: @rafix07 thanks. So reassignment reference is the problem, not polymorphic type. Wondering why there isn't an error for such mistake though.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here. Firstly - references in C++ are not rebindable like pointers. Which means that code like this:

```
int a = 1;
int& ref = a; // ref refers to a
int b = 2;
ref = b; // ref STILL referes to a
```

leaves you with `a == 2` and `b == 2`. It's just how it works.

Second problem is so called object slicing. If you think about it it's only logical that since references work with polymprphism code like this is legal:

```
class A{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void foo() override {}
};

class C : public A {
public:
    void foo() override {}
};

int main() {
    auto c = C{};
    A& a = c;
    auto b = B{};
    a = b;
}
```

What is going on here? Well, the `A` part of object `c` is being replaced wtih `A` part of object B according to `A::operator=` that is generated by default by the compiler. You can put some output in `A::operator=` to confirm what I am saying here.

Put these two things together and you have your problem. How to avoid it? First - if you want to rebind reference either use `std::reference_wrappper` or plain old pointer. Second - consider declaring `operator=()` deleted for your interfaces/abstract classes. This will make compiler generate error when trying to slice objects by mistake.

Some of your code after proposed fixes:

```
class Command
{
public:
    Command& operator=(const Command&) = delete;
    virtual void execute() = 0;
    virtual ~Command() = default; // <-- this is good practice
};
////............... rest of code here
class SimpleRemote
{
public:
    SimpleRemote(Command& command) : m_command{ command } {}

    void SetCommand(Command& command)
    {
        m_command = command;
    }

    void ButtonPressed()
    {
        m_command.get().execute();
    }

private:
    std::reference_wrapper<Command> m_command;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

References must be initialized but cannot be updated. Unfortunately, compiler will not warn you! You can see an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728233/why-are-references-not-reseatable-in-c).

You must use a pointer instead of a reference:

```
class SimpleRemote
{
public:
    SimpleRemote( Command& command ) : m_command{ &command } {}

    void SetCommand( Command& command )
    {
        m_command = &command;
    }

    void ButtonPressed()
    {
        m_command->execute();
    }

private:
    Command* m_command;
};
```